# Adjusting temperature output from DHT22 python script

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I need to adjust the temperature output from a DHT22 connected to a Raspberry pi Zero. The DHT22 is situated onto the RasPi case and the heat from the Pi gives a false output compare to the ambient temperature. I need to get the output to be 5 degrees Celsius lower.

I have this script working:

```
  streamer = Streamer(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, bucket_key=BUCKET_KEY, access_key=ACCESS_KEY)
while True:
    humidity, temp_c = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)
    if METRIC_UNITS:
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(C)", temp_c)
    else:
        temp_f = format(temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0, ".2f")
        streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Temperature(F)", temp_f)
    humidity = format(humidity,".2f")
    streamer.log(SENSOR_LOCATION_NAME + " Humidity(%)", humidity)
    streamer.flush()
    time.sleep(60*MINUTES_BETWEEN_READS)
```

Please help me amend the code.

Comment: Did you try using `-5` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Please format the code, Python is especially sensitive regarding indentation and becomes pretty unreadable if no indentation is visible.

Comment: Robert answered me below and it works. :-) Thank you for all of your time. :-)

Comment: @mkrieger1 I did try to add -5 (a lot of times) in different places in the code, but I could not get it to do what I needed. Hence my question here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner I am sorry, but when I see my question here the code is formatted??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just update your temperature read from the sensor to be 5 degrees lower? Such as

```
humidity, temp_c = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 4)
temp_c = temp_c - 5
rest of logic goes here....
```

Comment: Thank you Robert, that did the trick! I had tried different ways, but could not get it to work. :-)